# How to convert individual attribute to column name?

Tags: r

I need to convert the attributes of an indicator to column name.I have used tidyr library but it seems like there is a limit to which you can convert.
The below mentioned code is not the actual table,as the table has around 800 attributes.

```
Country<- c("India", "India","India", "Russia", "Russia","Russia","USA","USA","India","India","India","Russia","Russia","USA","USA")
Indicator <- c("Mortality", "Education", "Poverty", "Mortality", "Education", "Poverty","Mortality","Education","Mortality","Education","Poverty","Education","Poverty","Education","Poverty")
Value<-c(40,54,68,28,70,30,11,80,30,60,40,20,60,7,95)
Year<-c(1965,1965,1965,1965,1965,1965,1965,1965,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003,2003)
dat <- data.frame(Country,Indicator,Year,Value) 
Indicators<-spread(dat,Indicator,Value)
```

Comment: It seems odd to have an upper limit on it. R can easily handle data.frames with >800 columns. Are you getting an error, and if so, what is it?

Comment: You may try with `dcast` from `data.table`

Comment: Just tried `spread` with 3000 Indicator levels and it worked perfectly. You might have to provide some further indication of what is going wrong for you.

Comment: In the environment section it is given that my new table has around 1256 columns but when i try to display the same table it displaying only the first 60 or so columns.